# Rotating around an object in a circle

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm drawing a wind-turbine and I'm trying to figure out how I should draw the blades so they rotate around in a circle. Initially, I'm trying to draw one blade that rotates in a circle but I'm having a hard time understanding how to do it. All mine does is go till a certain angle and then comes back...here's my code :

```
  var t = model_transform;
  model_transform = t;
  var temp = Math.PI/180;
  var degreeOfRot = 45;
  var time = Math.sin(graphics_state.animation_time/2000); //Represents the graphics time
  model_transform = mult(model_transform, translation(0,0,0));
  model_transform = mult(model_transform, rotation(degreeOfRot*time, 0.0,0.0,1.0));
  model_transform = mult(model_transform, scale(0.3,0.9,0));
  this.shapes.box.draw(graphics_state,model_transform,this.red);
```

I've been looking at other answers on stack and still haven't figured it out...I feel like its something to do with the math but not sure

Comment: `a certain angle` - any idea what angle?

Comment: can you provide  fiddle?

Comment: do **NOT** provide a fiddle. Use a snippet!!

Also, pictures of what you're trying to achieve would be helpful. You might find [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) helpful and maybe [this one](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrix-stack.html) or [this one](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html)

Comment: code snippet syntax fixed. Look live demo now ...

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like (note: I'm using a unit cube centered around the origin so there's an extra scale to make it long and an extra translation to move the origin)

```
// spread the blades round the circle
const rotationOffset = i / settings.numBlades * Math.PI * 2;

// rotate around Z
world = m4.multiply(world, m4.rotationZ(rotationOffset + time));

// move it away from center 
world = m4.multiply(world, m4.translation([settings.xoff, settings.yoff, 0]));

// scale the unit cube to be long in Y
world = m4.multiply(world, m4.scaling([1, 10, 1]));

// the unit cube is centered around the origin. It's 1 unit big
// so this tranlation will move it's origin to the bottom left edge
world = m4.multiply(world, m4.translation([-.5, .5, 0]));
```

You might find [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) helpful and maybe [this one](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrix-stack.html) or [this one](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html)

```js
const vs = `
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;

attribute vec4 position;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
}
`;
const fs = `
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
`;


"use strict";
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const v3 = twgl.v3;
const gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl");

const settings = {
  xoff: 0,
  yoff: 0,
  numBlades: 1,
};

// compiles shaders, links program, looks up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for positions, texcoords
const centerBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 24, 12);
const bladeBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  const fov = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const zNear = 0.5;
  const zFar = 100;
  const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);

  const eye = [0, 0, -40];
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];

  const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  const viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // draw center
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, centerBufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    u_color: [1, 0.5, 1, 1],
    u_worldViewProjection: m4.translate(viewProjection, [0, 0, 1]),
  });

  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, centerBufferInfo);
  
  
  // draw blades

  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bladeBufferInfo);

  for (let i = 0; i < settings.numBlades; ++i) {
    let world = m4.identity();
    
    // spread the blades round the circle
    const rotationOffset = i / settings.numBlades * Math.PI * 2;
  
    // rotate around Z
    world = m4.multiply(world, m4.rotationZ(rotationOffset + time));

    // move it away from center 
    world = m4.multiply(world, m4.translation([settings.xoff, settings.yoff, 0]));

    // scale the unit cube to be long in Y
    world = m4.multiply(world, m4.scaling([1, 10, 1]));

    // the unit cube is centered around the origin. It's 1 unit big
    // so this tranlation will move it's origin to the bottom left edge
    world = m4.multiply(world, m4.translation([-.5, .5, 0]));

    // calls gl.uniformXXX
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_color: [1, 0, 0, 1],
      u_worldViewProjection: m4.multiply(viewProjection, world),
    });

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bladeBufferInfo);
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

setupSlider("#xoffSlider", "#xoff", "xoff", 10);
setupSlider("#yoffSlider", "#yoff", "yoff", 10);
setupSlider("#bladesSlider", "#blades", "numBlades", 1);

function setupSlider(sliderId, labelId, property, divisor) {
  const slider = document.querySelector(sliderId);
  const label = document.querySelector(labelId);

  function updateLabel() {
    label.textContent = settings[property];
  }

  slider.addEventListener('input', e => {
    settings[property] = parseInt(slider.value) / divisor;
    updateLabel();
  });

  updateLabel();
  slider.value = settings[property];
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { display: block; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
#ui { 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 10px; 
  top: 10px; 
  z-index: 2; 
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<div id="ui">
  <div><input id="xoffSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100"/><label>xoff: <span id="xoff"></span></label></div>
  <div><input id="yoffSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100"/><label>yoff: <span id="yoff"></span></label></div>
  <div><input id="bladesSlider" type="range" min="1" max="20"/><label>blades: <span id="blades"></span></label></div>
</div>
```